# Rails: getting data from an external database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to read some data from an external database and display it into my home page. Here's how far I've gotten:

In my database.yml file:

```
external_db:
  adapter:  mysql2
  database: external_src
  username: external_src
  password: mypassword
  host: myblog.com
```

I did not have a pages model, so I created one: /app/models/pages.rb

and added the following to it:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:external_db)
  set_table_name :posts
end
```

Now, in my pages controller, how do I retrieve data? Let's say I have a table in that database called pots and I would like to retrieve the post with the id 2?

Answer (score 0):

Like any other model so using `#find` method, i.e.:

```
Blog.find(2)
```

Should work

<sub>Untested</sub>

Comment: It's giving me an error message: uninitialized constant PagesController::Blog

Comment: I feel that is something wrong with your model loader. But I don't have idea what. I try to get that error but I promise nothing.

Comment: I would suggest that you should try retrieve it in console first

Comment: Retrieve what in Console? Blog.find(2)? it will give the same error I got in the runtime.